# Using package.json config object variables under windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, package.json

Does anybody know how to use variables from package.json config object under windows? Here is my current config object:

```
"config": {
    "webpack_server_port": "8080",
    "mockup_server_port": "3000"
}
```

And here is my npm script command:

```
"dev:server": "npm run clean && webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port $npm_package_config_webpack_server_port",
```

It's working fine under Linux and MAC OS, but windows have problem with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
"dev:server": "npm run clean && webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --port %npm_package_config_webpack_server_port%"
```

Comment: Will this work also under Linux and MAC OS? I need some cross platform solution

Comment: No it works only under windows. You could write a batch file to check the os. Then you just have to call the script from your package script.

Comment: you could also create two scripts. one for windows `dev:server:win` and one for linux and Mac, `dev:server:lin`. And maybe one default `"dev:server": "npm run dev:server:lin"`

Answer (score 1):

For Linux and windows:

Use cross-env's cross-env-shell

`"dev:server": "cross-env-shell 'echo ${npm_package_config_webpack_server_port}'"`

[Source](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/192#issuecomment-524014891)